# generating javascript string in python

Tags: javascript, python, cheetah

i have string stored in python variables, and i am outputting a html that contains javascript, and the i need to create javascript variables.

for ex, in python

```
title = "What's your name?"
```

i use Cheetah to generate the html.
Cheetah code:

```
var title = '$title';
```

how do i escape this correctly so that a correct javascript variable is created?
actual html output needed:

```
var title = 'What\'s your name?';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want JSON:

```
import simplejson as sj
print sj.dumps('What\'s your name?') # => '"What\'s your name?"'
```

Don't generate js with cheetah, there are libraries.

Comment: this works great! thanks a lot, can you tell what libraries are available that i can use?

Comment: THC4k

thanks for this, when I tried this the output works correctly in python. but the actual html output from Cheetah does not have the escape character. do you know what is going on?

Comment: Please note that this isn't sufficient to escape untrusted input. e.g. "str</script>" => "str</script>" breaks existing JS!

Comment: @MaximilianHils No, as long as you enclose the JS section in a `CDATA`, or don't use XHTML you're fine: you just have a JS string containing HTML.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: I am not so sure about this: https://jsfiddle.net/rey9e5k7/

Comment: @MaximilianHils Ignore my brainfart: You're correct. What needs to happen is the output from escaping the Javascript needs to subsequently be escaped for HTML if embedding it in HTML. If your template is generating stand-alone JS file (unusual, but we have some code which does it to genereate data files for loading into the browser) then it's not necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Either just do `title = title.replace("'", "\\'")` in Python before the `title` value gets to Cheetah, or add a custom filter to Cheetah for the purpose and invoke it in the template.  Doing it on the Python side of things seems simpler, though.